# Does STRAPI helpful to develop REST api to connect Flutter app easily and cost effectively

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, graphql, strapi

These days, I'm developing a Car Service application using Flutter. I already developed my flutter app using mock data with json files. This is my flutter app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clivekumara.srilankacarwashfinder

Now I want to develop own rest api. Basically below requirements should be handled in the rest api.
 1. Image Uploding and store images 
 2. Mange authentications
 3. Other entity crud operations 
 4. Location base functionalities.

For fullfill above requirements I research a backend techologies. This api sholud be faster and easy to implement. Also deployment cost sholud be less.

For that I choose **StrApi CMS** platform with Mongodb to develop this requirement.

Can you give me some idea that choson technologies are compatible with the requirement. What are the cost effective deployment technologies (Hosting space, Database server etc...) compatibility with this Strapi and mongodb .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use strapi for building static websites. Its pretty easy to use and build fast API. I also saw some Flutter apps built with strapi backend and they work flawlessly. It seems to be a good choice but might be challenging sometimes specially if you are building a very complex app.

You can use Heroku for strapi hosting. They have a free plan that will be enough for development purpose. Note that Heroku does not give you space for your uploads like images. You will still need to buy some space on S3 or [Digitalcean](https://m.do.co/c/c8d6e09fd24b) spaces or other services.
[DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/c8d6e09fd24b) has a Oneclick installation of Strapi. It costs $10/month and if you add a $5/month space to your plan then you have $15/month to start. For database Strapi comes with SQL Lite by default but you should use Postgres or MangoDB to build your project for production.

Comment: Thank you ! please can you give some idea to this points -> Hosting space, Database server

Comment: You can use Heroku for strapi hosting. They have a free plan that will be enough for development purpose. Note that Heroku does not give you space for your uploads like images. You will still need to create a space on S3 or Digitalcean spaces or any other services. 
DigitalOcean has a Oneclick installation of strapi. It costs $10/month and if you add a $5/month space to your plan then you have $15/month to start.

For database you can use Postgres or MangoDB. 
Strapi comes with SQL Lite by default but dont do this because you will have problem when trying to deploy your website

Comment: I used DigitalOcean . Thank you